Maximum table size in PieCloudDB
Is there a maximum table size limit in PieCloudDB Database like PostgreSQL?
The table size in PostgreSQL is limited by the maximum number of blocks in the table, which is 2^32 blocks. PostgreSQL's block size can be adjusted to contain up to 32KB, so the maximum table size is 128TB.

Unlike PostgreSQL, PieCloudDB does not limit the table size during design. However, whether there is an upper limit in actual case requires self-testing.
